# Detecting when modal opens - Bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to detect when a modal opens so i can set the content height but simply does nothing.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
$('#bootModal').on('show', function () {
  alert('foo'); // doesn't fire
  $(this).find('.modal-body').css({
    'height':$( window ).height()*0.8
  });
});
```

Any ideas why it's not detecting the modal opening?

Comment: The event name is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Bootstrap 3, the event is `shown.bs.modal` not `show`

> **shown.bs.modal**    This event is fired when the modal has been made
>   visible to the user (will wait for CSS transitions to complete). If
>   caused by a click, the clicked element is available as the
>   relatedTarget property of the event.

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Sample: http://plnkr.co/edit/xp3GdIHF8rKLm8h6UhlL?p=preview

Comment: Changed `show` to `shown.bs.modal` but no difference, still not firing the alert or making a change to height

Comment: Hmmm - I just tried it within the JS file where I need it and it works too, many thanks for that. I had the function in a separate js file where i'd prefer it and I'm guessing it didn't read it because of that.